# Why I get "cache" in the output of `ip route get`?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, linux-kernel, iproute2

I'm using kernel 5.11.0 and in the ip-route manual [1] it can be read:

```
Starting with Linux kernel version 3.6, there is no routing cache
for IPv4 anymore. Hence ip route show cached will never print any
entries on systems with this or newer kernel versions.
```

If I type `ip route show table cache` there is no output, as expected.

However, when I type: `ip route get 10.0.10.44` this is the output:

```
10.0.10.44 dev eth0 src 10.0.10.40 uid 1000 
    cache
```

Why does it say `cache` if there is no cache? I am confused

[1] https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-route.8.html

Answer (score 3):

It seems there were two different "caches" before, the routing cache and the forwarding information base (FIB). The latter remains and is called cache as well (e.g. http://linux-ip.net/html/routing-cache.html) thus the confusion. This link helped https://workshop.netfilter.org/2013/wiki/images/2/2a/DaveM_route_cache_removed_nfws2013.pdf